# Object inspector in Delphi 12

Tags: delphi, delphi-12-athens, object-inspector

[image]

I have upgraded to Delphi 12, and I ran into a problem: Often the "Object Inspector" window isn't drawing, its just blank, like shown on the image.

The only solution I've found sofar, is to restart Delphi.

Does any one have a solution for this?

Comment: This is a known bug.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand do you know the Quality Portal ticket number?  I know it was a known bug in 10.4. but it was fixed in 11.  https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-30949

Comment: This was supposed to be fixed several times now but it seems Embarcadero just can't get to the bottom of the cause. I see you are using object inspector as standalone (undocked) window. Try docking it back to the main window of Delphi to see if the problem persists.

Comment: I have the same issue, but have managed a (shorter) workaround. Save a desktop setup with various other configurations of the windows (remember to keep your preferred one), and when the issue appears, switch back and forth between the saved desktops (always returning to your preferred one) and at some point (2 or 3 switches) it'll redraw the object inspector window again - for a while...

Comment: Thx @HeartWare i'll try that. 

Does that also fix the drawing problems on non visual components.?

Comment: I haven't seen that issue - but perhaps I've just not noticed it. IOW: I don't know :-)